# What is the name of node after pushing the new node as a head in c?

Tags: c, linked-list

I started learning the linked list. I've pasted my code down below. I have one doubt. When I insert a node at front, I made it as a head. So whenever I want to print, I'll call the printlist(head). What if I want print from the second node? Initially I named it as head. Now what will it be? I also learned that random access is not possible in linked list. But I can print from wherever node I want. Please clarify.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node{
    char data;
    struct node* next;
};

void printlist(struct node* n)
{
    while(n!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%c\n",n->data);
        n=n->next;
    }
}

void InsertNodeAtFirst(struct node** head_ref)
{
    printf("Node insertion at first\n");
    struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    newnode->data='a';
    newnode->next= *head_ref;
    *head_ref = newnode;
    printf("\n");
    printlist(newnode);
}

void InsertNodeAfter(struct node* previous_node)
{
    if(previous_node==NULL)
        printf("Previous node cannot be blank or NULL\n");

    printf("Node insertion at middle\n");   
    struct node* middlenode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    middlenode->data='c';
    middlenode->next=previous_node->next;
    previous_node->next = middlenode;
    printf("\n");
    printlist(previous_node);
}

void InsertNodeAtEnd(struct node** LastNode)
{
    printf("Node insertion at End\n");
    struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    struct node* last = *LastNode;

    newnode->data='f';
    newnode->next=NULL;

    while(last->next!=NULL)
    {
        last=last->next;
    }

    last->next=newnode;
    printf("\n");

}

int main(void)
{
    struct node* head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    struct node* second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    struct node* third = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));

    head->data='b';
    head->next=second;
    second->data='d';
    second->next=third;
    third->data='e';
    third->next=NULL;

    printlist(head);
    InsertNodeAtFirst(&head);
    InsertNodeAfter(head);
    InsertNodeAtEnd(&head);
    printlist(head);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What if I want print from the second node?*  for this pass the particular node address to `printlist()` function.

For e.g in your main function, after creating the linked list ask the user from which node you want to print. Let's say `n=2`

For e.g

`InsertNodeAtFirst(&head);`

`struct node *temp = head;`

`/* make temp to point to the node which you want */`

`/* Find particular node address from where you want to print */`

`for(int row= 0; row < n; row++){`

```
   if(temp->next != NULL)

           temp = temp->next;
```

`}`

And now call the `printlist()` as

`printlist(temp);`

*I also learned that random access is not possible in linked list ?* it's only possible  if you know the address of that node & to get that, you have to traverse from `head` node.

Answer (score 0):

Head will always be your first list node. If you want to have access to the second one, you will use `head->next`.

When you add a new element in a list, your current node becomes the next pointer of the new node, and the new node pointer becomes the head.

If you want to have access to the third, then you need to have access to the next pointer of the next pointer of the new head, which makes it `head->next-next`

Answer (score 0):

> When I insert a node at front, I made it as a head. So whenever I want
>   to print, I'll call the printlist(head). What if I want print from the
>   second node? Initially I named it as head. Now what will it be?

The name `head` refers to the head, the expression `head->next` refers to the element that follows the head, etc.

> I also learned that random access is not possible in linked list. But
>   I can print from wherever node I want. Please clarify.

**Random access** has special meaning. It means that you are able to access any element you want, generally with its index, in **an efficient way**. There is no random access possible in a true linked list because if you want to access element n, you need to start from head, then find next, then next, etc. So the total cost to access element n is n operations. This is not really efficient as the number of operations needed to access an element increases with the index of that element. Very common random access structures are arrays.